# Prove that the union of two equivalence relations on the same set an equivalence relation iff?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ and $E$ be equivalence relations on set $A$.

Prove that $R\cup E$ is an equivalence relation on set A  iff for all $a\in A$,  $[a]_{R} \subseteq [a]_{E}$ OR $[a]_{E} \subseteq [a]_{R}$.

Someone can help me here ?
I don't have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What's $a$? Is a quantor missing?

Comment: @joriki fixed,sorry.

Comment: That can't be true -- the conditions for different values of $a$ clearly don't imply each other. I still suspect you intended to quantify over $a$?

Comment: It's actually not that much clearer. Do you mean that $\{[a]_R|a\in A\} \subseteq \{[a]_E|a\in A\}$ (or the other way)?

Comment: $[a]_{R} \subseteq A$ and $[a]_{E} \subseteq A$ for every $a\in A$.

Comment: @joriki $a/R \subseteq a/E$ or $a/E \subseteq a/R$.

Comment: @Noam: Yes, I understand the equivalence class notation. But the claim is false in its present form. You claim that $R\cup E$ being an equivalence relation is equivalent to this condition for arbitrary $a$. But the conditions for different $a$ are clearly not equivalent, hence they can't all be equivalent to the same thing, regardless of what that thing is. I'd be surprised if you don't find if you carefully check the problem that it says either "there exists an $a\in A$" or "for all $a\in A$".

Comment: for all $a\in A$.
Take a look now, I have fixed that.

Comment: @Noam: All that effort could have been saved if you'd responded to one of my earlier questions whether a quantor is missing.

Comment: @joriki My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $R\cup E$ is an equivalence relation, and suppose $[a]_R\not\subset[a]_E,$ i.e. $\exists b\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ but $(a,b)\not\in E.$ Then $\forall c\in A$ such that $(a, c)\in E,$ as $(c, a), (a, b)\in R\cup E,$ we must have $(c, b)\in R\cup E,$ thus $(c, b)\in R$ (if $(c,b)\in E,$ then $(a,b)\in E$). This shows that $(a,c)\in R.$ Thus $[a]_E\subset[a]_R.$
Conversely suppose that $[a]_E\subseteq[a]_R$ (the other case is similar). Then, if $(a,b), (b, c)\in R\cup E,$ we can suppose without loss of generality that $(a,b)\in R, (b,c)\in E.$ Then by our hypothesis, $(b,c)\in R.$ Thus $(a,c)\in R\subseteq R\cup E.$ This shows that $R\cup E$ is an equivalence relation (the other two axioms always hold).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reflexivity and symmetry are clearly inherited from $R$ and $E$.

If $R\cup E$ is transitive, then since $a\sim_{R\cup E}b$ for all $b\in[a]_R$ and $a\sim_{R\cup E}c$ for all $c\in[a]_E$, also $b\sim_{R\cup E}c$ for all such $b,c$, and the inclusion condition follows.

If $R\cup E$ is not transitive, we have $b\sim_{R\cup E}a$ and $a\sim_{R\cup E}c$ but not $b\sim_{R\cup E}c$, which can only occur if one of $b,c$ is only in $[a]_R$ and the other is only in $[a]_E$, violating the inclusion condition.